# horizontal listbox that could be infinite circle scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollviewer

I would like to make a horizontal listbox that could be infinite scrolling (looping listbox/scrollviewer, or circular listbox/scrollviewer), means that when I scroll to its end, its would scroll over from beginning.

I have tried to make the listbox horizontal, but it wouldn't scroll so I put it inside a scrollviewer to have it scroll horizontally. However it's not the listbox that scroll and I need them somehow to scroll over from beginning.

This is what I have so far:

```
        private void DoWebClient()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://music.mobion.vn/api/v1/music/userstop?devid="));
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);

    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {            
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
        {

            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Stream str = e.Result;
            str.Position = 0;
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(str);


                var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("user")
                           select new mobion
                           {
                               avlink = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("avlink"),
                               nickname = (string)query.Element("user_info").Element("nickname"),
                               track = (string)query.Element("track"),
                               artist = (string)query.Element("artist"),
                           };                                        
                listBox.ItemsSource = data;                                    
        }            
    }
```

Mainpage.xaml

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="forever" Completed="Storyboard1_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:25" To="-2400" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="imagesScrollview" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="8,563,-2400,2" Width="auto" x:Name="imagesScrollview" Opacity="1" Background="#FF3ED216" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <im:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="#FF3ED216" ManipulationCompleted="listBox_ManipulationCompleted">
            <ListBox.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </ListBox.RenderTransform>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" />
                        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,0">
                        <Image Name="imageAV" Source="{Binding Path=avlink}" Height="80" Width="80" Stretch="UniformToFill" MouseLeftButtonUp="imageAV_MouseLeftButtonUp" ImageFailed="imageAV_ImageFailed" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <TextBlock Name="indexTextBlock" Text="{Binding num}" />
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding nickname}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding track}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding artist}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: How many items are you planning for the list?

Comment: I need to get a list to display user information from this website: http://music.mobion.com/api/v1/music/userstop?devid= so I would say about 35-40 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a listbox scroll horizontally you need to set the ScrollBar Visibility properties of the internal ScrollViewer.
Like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
```

The [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) includes a `LoopingSelector` class that you could based your own control implementation on. There's an example of creating such a control at http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/wp7-looping-selector/ (although it is for a vertical list)

Comment: Thanks you for your example, that is how I would want to implement for my listbox. Similar to the Arlarms app on windows phone 7, you could scroll the time from 1 to 60 and return to 1 and reverse. However I want it horizontally. I will try to work with LoopingSelector.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have check out the loopingSelector, however there are some problem, I don't want the unselected item to fade away and selected item always stay in middle, moreover was asked to make it automatically rolling...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that helps, but the standard approach to infinite scrolling is to put at least one screenful of duplicate items from the beginning of the list at the end, and upon reaching the end, transparently skip (1-step scroll) to the beginning or a fixed short offset from it (and vice versa) so that it looks the same but the user looks at the items from the beginning of the list, not their duplicates from the end.

Comment: Should I use Blend 4 or Visual studio to archive this? And what should be the approach? I try to search on google for 2 day but couldn't find anything.